# Converting to geojson from db values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, geojson

I am new to postgreSQL.In my project i have a table and i need to make all field as a json format. I tried below code

```
SELECT row_to_json(f) As feature 
 FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type 
 , ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::json As geometry 
 , row_to_json((SELECT l FROM (SELECT objectid) As l)) As properties 
 FROM plutoreferencedata As l WHERE l.objectid = '3') As f;
```

I got result like below

> "{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[979999.082000002,196493.280000001],[979897.966399997,196147.8204],[979718.105800003,196197.441599995],[979823.056799993,196549.6884],[979999.082000002,196493.280000001]]]]},"properties": (...)"

Just look the result. Inside properties it shows some ... only.. Please help me to get the values inside the property. Desired output looks like below

```
>   {    "geometry":{
>       "type":"MultiPolygon",
>       "coordinates":[
>          [
>             [
>                [
>                   -309443.24253826,
>                   388111.579584133
>                ],
>                [
>                   -134666.391073443,
>                   239616.414560895
>                ],
>                [
>                   -308616.222736376,
>                   238788.813082666
>                ],
>                [
>                   -309443.24253826,
>                   388111.579584133
>                ]
>             ]
>          ]
>       ]    },    "type":"Feature",    "properties":{
>       "objectid":'3'    } }
```

In my case object id is a text value.. Please help me for this. This will be great if u can give me the solution...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks one again for your answer @Leonardo Alves and @D T. I found one more option for the same.[image]

execute and save the result will give complete output values instead of dots.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that the output includes the `(...)` instead of listing your properties, that is a side effect of whatever GUI you are using to run the query.  pgAdmin for example will only show you so much output before adding the `(...)`.

[image]

Double clicking on the field `(...)` will open a dialog box that shows the entire query result and will allow you to copy it all.

[image]

Comment: Just as an FYI, there are a couple of other methods for generating GeoJSON out of postgres: https://gist.github.com/dmofot/a382ea40b798cd18ea4b45eb62ecf97f